# Cannot solve a differential equation using Laplace transformations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$\dddot x + x = 2t$, $x(0)=0$, $\dot x(0)=1$, $\ddot x(0)=0$ and the answer should be $x=t^2-2+2\cos{t}+\sin{t}$

---

I start off with assuming $L(x)=X(p)$ then $$\dddot x=p^3X(p)-p^2X(0)-pX'(0)-X''(0)=p^3X-p$$
$$p^3X-p+X=\frac2{p^2}$$
$$X=\frac2{p^2(p^3+1)}+\frac{p}{p^3+1}=2\frac1{p^2}+\frac13\frac1{p+1}-\frac13\frac{p+1}{p^2-p+1}$$
$$\frac{p+1}{p^2-p+1}=\frac{p-\frac12+\frac12+1}{p^2-p+\frac14+\frac34}=\frac{p-\frac12}{(p-\frac12)^2+\frac34}+\sqrt{3}\frac{\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}{(p-\frac12)^2+\frac34}$$
$$X=2t +\frac13e^{-t}-\frac13e^{\frac{t}2}cos{\frac{\sqrt3}2t}-\frac{\sqrt3}3e^{\frac{t}2}sin{\frac{\sqrt3}2t}$$

Comment: Your "correct" answer does not satisfy the ODE. I don't see anything wrong in your work so far.

Comment: Is there a dot missing? I would suspect $\dddot x+\dot x=2t$, as that fits the set of necessary characteristic roots for the given solution.

Comment: Ok I solved $\dddot x+\dot x = 2t$ and got the answer I was supposed to also thank you to the guy that showed me how to decompose the last part of the equation I had posted.

Answer (score 1):

If $\dddot x+\dot x=2t, x(0)=\ddot x(0)=0, \dot x(0)=1$
$$p^3X-p+pX=\frac2{p^2}$$
$$X=\frac{p^3+2}{p^3(p^2+1)}=\frac{A}{p^3}+\frac{B}{p^2}+\frac{C}{p}+\frac{Dp+E}{p^2+1}$$
$$A=2, B=0, C=-2, D=2, E=1$$
$$X=2\frac1{p^2}-2\frac1{p}+\frac{2p+1}{p^2+1}=2\frac1{p^2}-2\frac1{p}+2\frac{p}{p^2+1}+\frac1{p^2+1}=2t^2-2+2cost+sint$$
which matches the answer I've been given. Thanks to @Lutz Lehmann for pointing it out